# Google Trends not working on my computer

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-trends

I've been using Google Trends for my project alongside a Python API called Pytrend. and it's due in soon. Today, just a couple of hours ago, suddenly, I'm unable to use Google Trends. Every time I search a word, I get the following error

Oops! There was a problem displaying this page.
Please try again

Hence Pytrends doesn't work either.
I read that it maybe due to an ad blocker preventing access to Google Trends, but my anti-virus Norton 360 allows Google Chrome, and I don't have any Google Chrome extension ad blocker either.

Can someone please help provide a solution? I need one really soon. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I accessed Google Trends far more frequently than most people due to my project being centered on Pytrend's API.
Therefore, Google presumably thought I was a bot or that my activity was suspicious.
I simply restarted my modem, and Google Trends, and hence, Pytrends, now both work.
So simply restart your modem and possibly your computer as well just to be on the safe side. And it should work right after.